# How to create a tar.gz package to upload to your ppa

Tags: packaging, launchpad

I have created an application using Qt. I have two folders in the project , one containing the source code and other the binaries, makefile etc.
   I created an archive , used dh_make etc. and uploaded the package to ppa. But my archive simply contains two folders. How do create a tar.gz file which contains usr/share/icons, and other folders as other applications have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put compiled binaries in the tarball (tar.gz), just the source code. Then use the debian packaging helper scripts to create a debianized singed source package (command would be `debuild -S` IIRC) and upload the dsc file to the PPA. Launchpad will then build the actual debian packages with binaries and the correct directory structure depending on the configuration. To not stress launchpads resources more than neccessary you should try pbuilder first on you local machine. The Ubuntu wiki has a [complete packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/) and more on that topic.

Comment: Your link is broken: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

Comment: Maybe you use 7zip, and that can be install in softwarecenter, and sudo apt-get install 7zip